# Bash script - Command fails when run as variable, but works otherwise

Tags: bash, pipewire

I have a simple script, but for some reason it fails when running the command as a variable. Any ideas as to why?
(I am trying to change device setting of pipewire with a script)

```
cmd2="pactl set-card-profile 'bluez_card.B8_F8_BE_79_40_C0' 'headset-head-unit-msbc'"
$cmd2  
#Command above Fails with "Failure: No such entity"

pactl set-card-profile 'bluez_card.B8_F8_BE_79_40_C0' 'headset-head-unit-msbc'
#command above works fine. (if I modify the bluez to blue99 it fails as cmd2 did)
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). This is normal and expected. Commands can be safely stored as arrays or as functions -- not as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this worked.. but removing the ' fixed it..

```
cmd2="pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.B8_F8_BE_79_40_C0 headset-head-unit-msbc"
$cmd2
```

Comment: BashFAQ #50 explains why. However, it would be much better to switch to an approach that allows all possible commands to work, as described in the linked duplicate and in the aforementioned FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. learning more every day!